# How to correctly store text as a number in Excel cell

Tags: c#, excel

After searching other topics on the site and did not find the right answer I open my own thread. If it exists and I have not seen please comment.

I create a Excel worksheet programmatically through C# (using Microsoft.Office.Interop). I fill the cells with a soap request, blah blah blah.

The issue is, for each field I have the value (currency) as a string, with the following formats `X`, `X,X` or `X,XX` (spanish culture). So when I fill each field with the text, if the string have the "X" format it is store as number, otherwise I have the warning message "Number stored as text"

So I have tried converting the string to number and then I fill the cell, which has a currency format, and the result is right in the excel sheet, but the cell value was wrong rounded.

I just need convert from the string to a decimal value with only 2 ciphers.

```
xlRng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A100");
xlRng.Style.NumberFormat = "0,00";

xlWorkSheet.Cells[2,1] = Convert.ToSingle(stringWithValue);
```

For example:

- String value = 86,72
- Cell value (in the excel sheet) = 86,72 --> It's
  right
- Cell value (in the formula textfield) = 86,7200012207031

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DECIMAL-function-ee554665-6176-46ef-82de-0a283658da2e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1. Stay away from singles and doubles if you can, they give you this sort of mess.

Comment: It works fine, very simple… Post it a answer and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay away from doubles and singles if possible.

`= Decimal("86,72",10) where 10 is base 10

should do it.